# call page method without script manager from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, scriptmanager, pagemethods

---

How to call page method from jquery without using scriptmanager

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried and explain in what ways it is not performing as expected and what you want to achieve. There is no question here.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "webpage.aspx/methodName",
    data: "{id: '" + id + "'}",
    success: getTargetSuccess,
    error: getTargetFailure
});

function getTargetSuccess(result,e)
{ 
    var data = result.d;
}

function getTargetFailure(result,e)
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Excellent guide here: http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/