# How to pass parameter from javascript to code behind?

Tags: asp.net, parameters, pagemethods

i tried pass parameter from jscript to code behind, but it don't work.
My code:

[C#]

```
[WebMethod]
public static String sendEmail(String str)
{
     ...
     msg.body = str;
     ...
     return str;
}
```

[jscript]

If i use function alert, it return null

```
function onOkClickButton()
{
    var content = "Hello";
    alert("<%=sendEmail(" + content + ")%>");
}
```

if i use PageMethod, my email's body is null

```
<asp:ScriptManager enablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager> 
function onOkClickButton()
{
    var content = "Hello";
    PageMethods.sendEmail(content, onSuccess, onError);
}
function onSuccess(text)
{
    alert(text)
}

function onError(text)
{
    alert(text)
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Have you done this: <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" 
    EnablePageMethods="true" 
    EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery ajax would be the easiest method, IMO:

```
function onOkClickButton()
{
    var content = "Hello";

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "urlToPageHostingSendEmail.aspx/sendEmail",
      data: { str: content }
    }).success(function( msg ) {
      alert( msg );
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, 
Function sendEmail was placed in MasterPage. 
But when i set url: "MasterPage.master.aspx/sendEmail", it don't work.

Comment: Having it in the master page feels dirty to me, and I'm not 100% certain it will work, but it very well may. I'm not currently in a position to test it. [This page is a good resource for properly configuring WebMethods in ASP.NET applications](http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/03/13/asp.net-ajax-callbacks-to-web-methods-in-aspx-pages.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery to call your page method:

[call page method without script manager from jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325721/call-page-method-without-script-manager-from-jquery)

or

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Also have a look at this video:

http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/430_Calling_Page_Methods_Using_JQuery_and_Returning_JSON_Result.aspx